# Bus terminal for wire interconnetion

Tags: busbar

So I have multiple wires (~5) from 0.75mm² to 10mm². I want to connect them like with Wago, but they are bigger than Wago can hold, and I need to fix them in place on panel.

[Example](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_Fuse_Block_LSCR_Datasheet-1222151.pdf). So these have holes to screw them on panel. This is exactly what I need.

But these things are expensive (~40$ per two blocks). What else could I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "like with Wago"? Would a screw-down terminal block suffice, or do you specifically want the lever action Wago connectors have?

Comment: Also, can you terminate the wires with connectors, or do they have to remain bare (or perhaps enferruled) wires?

Comment: I would prefer screw wire terminals for better reliability, so no bare wires. It is for shaky/vibrating environment.